# $regex to find whole words, mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

Find items containing a whole word.

```
const queryparam = 'microsoft';

mongoose.model('tag').find({name: { $regex:  new RegExp("\w"+queryparam+"\w" ), '$options': 'i' }});

// tag collection

    [
      {
         name: 'Microsoft word" // this should be returned by query
      },
      {
         name: 'Microsoft-word" // this should not be returned by query
      }
    ]
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (thanks to @Toto):

```
db.tag.find({
  name: {
    "$regex": "\\bMicrosoft\\b\\s",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_Kzkb0WR1Hs)

Comment: `[^\\w\\W]` means not any character, it doesn't match anything.

Comment: Fixed. I thought Zero-width space is ignored by `\b`. Thanks

Comment: The word boundary is redundant with the following `(\\s|$)`

Comment: "Microsoft" is an example, the variable queryparam should be used.

Comment: Replace Microsoft by `"+queryparam+"`